# Unable to plot Large Function with dgrid3d (gnuplot)

Tags: gnuplot

I'm attempting to graph a complex function in a 3D space using GNUPlot's C++ library.
I'm plotting [a large array of 3D points](https://anonymfile.com/Ep7Og/data.txt).

Whenever I try to plot my function with the `dgrid3d` option by sending the following plotting commands:

```
gp << "set dgrid3d 100,100\n";
gp << "splot" << gp.file1d(points) << "with pm3d title ' '" << endl;
```

(with `points` being an array of my 3D function points)

I either get a blank graph or a very broken graph:

[image]

I tried changing up the grid precision values, but it always appears to mess up the graphing for some reason.

The best I'm able to get is to simply plot it with `lines`:

[image]

I want to simply plot this as a solid surface, the color of which I want to map to another set of values.

What would be a better way of doing this? Is there another 3D graphing function that would be more suited to my needs?

Thanks for reading my post, any guidance is appreciated.

Comment: It is difficult to reproduce and make suggestions if we don't have your data. What does large mean, MBs, GBs? Is there maybe a way to provide the data to test?

Comment: I suggest you experiment with using other kernels for the gridding function.  For example `set dgrid3d gauss kdensity <dx>, <dy>`  where the dx and dy terms adjust the range of influence of each data point.

Comment: You're right, I edited my post above I pasted in all my data points in an online TXT file. There should be a hyperlink in my post above now.

Comment: I also tried the `set dgrid3d gauss kdensity <dx>, <dy>` command, and it appears that no matter what I put in for `<dx>, <dy>`, I always get a blank plot.

Comment: Your data link fails with a "file has been deleted" error

Comment: Sorry, it appears that service only held it till it was first downloaded. I used a new service now, should be a new hyperlink.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am unable to reproduce any problem in plotting this file.
The sequence:

```
set datafile separator comma
set palette defined (-1 "blue", 0 "white", 1 "red")
set dgrid3d 100,100
splot "data.text" with pm3d
```

[image]
produces the image above, which seems fine.  You might want to consider using some variant of log-scaling if there is supposed to be information in the middles region of the sampling.

However I don't actually think gridding + pm3d is the best way to visualize this data.  It seems clearer to me to simply use

```
set datafile separator comma
set xyplane at 0
splot "data.txt" with impulses
```

[image]

---

**Second round answer**

---

I think this figure will make clear what is happening.  The surface fit to your original commands `set dgrid3d 100,100` lies mostly in the range -2000 < z < -500.   So when you clip it to a thin slice near z=0 there is nothing there to show except the spikes you saw from the beginning. So no error; that really is what the slice of your surface looks like.

I don't know what your data represents, nor what a different expected surface might be. So it's hard to suggest how to generate it.

[image]

Here is one more suggestion for what might be a useful presentation of the data. It clips the color assignments to [-40:40] but does not clip the z-values that generate the map.

```
set datafile sep comma
set palette defined (-1 "blue", 0 "white", 1 "red")
set dgrid3d 100,100
set cbrange [-40:40]
unset border; set ticscale 0,0
set xlabel "X"; set ylabel "Y" norotate; set cblabel "Z" norotate
set view map

splot "data.text" using 1:2:3 with pm3d
```

[image]

---

### 3rd iteration

There are very few points near [0,0].  If you create a grid using a kernel function that spreads out the influence of each point over a large area, those few points with small |z| are dominated by the much larger number of points with very large |z|.

Here is an example of reducing the influence of each point to a local area with radius 2 and Gaussian fall-off of contribution.  The corresponding command is `set dgrid3d 100,100 gauss 2,2`.  It emphasizes very local variation at the cost of overall smoothness of the surface. You will have to decide based on the nature of your data whether that is an appropriate representation.

By the way, there is one point in your data set with an anomalous entry:
`1.000000,0.000000,-nan(ind)`
The program is basically ignoring it.   If it has some special significance you may want to edit that line to show either z=0 or z=, or place a dot on the surface to mark it or whatever else might be appropriate.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply;
That's all very insightful, however I think the main issue here is the fact that I'm clipping the Z-axis range down to -40 and 40, which can be seen in the original images I posted. I do this by setting `zrange` to `-40,40`. I tested it without the Z-axis clipping, and it looks the same as the graphs you posted in your reply. Is there a specific reason as to why clipping breaks the graph like that?

Comment: Could you back up and explain exactly what you are trying to do?   `set zrange [-40:40]` will accept the ~8000 data points lying in that range and exclude the ~7000 points outside that range.  Do you want to generate and plot a full surface from the truncated set of points, or generate a surface from the full set of points and then plot only a clipped portion of that surface?

Comment: The latter. I would like to generate a surface from the full set of points first, and plot only the clipped portion of that full surface. As far as I understand, that prevents uneven clipping at the edges of the plot.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply and the edit to your post. I believe this is definitely guiding me towards the answer. That new visualization of my data is striking. What is the most confusing to me, is the fact that in the last image you posted, the top-down 2D visualization of my data, it appears that the Z-value around the (0,0) position is below -40... When in fact, if we look at my data, the Z-values at (0,0) and around it are all close to 0... Is there a reason as to why `dgrid3d` treats all these Z-values as below -40, when in the data they are not?

Comment: Thank you so much for providing me all this assistance. The latest edit of your post appears to have solved my issue, the plot comes out as expected now.